Acumatica Cannot create an opportunity using code
I'm trying to create an opportunity using code.But somehow there is an error saying PX.Data.PXOuterException: 'Error: Inserting  'Opportunity Address' record raised at least one error. Please review the errors.'. I tried for hours to solve this issue. Some help would be appreciated. The error message also says that the CountryID cannot be empty. But its not empty.
        var graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<OpportunityMaint>();
        var opp = new CROpportunity();
        var addrs = new CRAddress();
        var bAddrs = new CRBillingAddress();
        var sAddrs = new CRShippingAddress();

        addrs.CountryID = "US";
        bAddrs.CountryID = "US";
        sAddrs.CountryID = "US";

        bAddrs.OverrideAddress = true;
        sAddrs.OverrideAddress = true;

        var addr1 = graph.Opportunity_Address.Insert(addrs);

        var addr2 = graph.Billing_Address.Insert(bAddrs);

        var addr3 = graph.Shipping_Address.Insert(sAddrs);

        graph.Save.Press();

        opp = graph.Opportunity.Insert(opp);

        opp.Status = "N";
        opp.ClassID = "PRODUCT";
        opp.StageID = "L";
        opp.CloseDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        opp.Subject = "This is the fake subject";

        opp.OpportunityAddressID = addr1.AddressID;
        opp.BillAddressID = addr2.AddressID;
        opp.ShipAddressID = addr3.AddressID;
       
        graph.Save.Press();


You can't insert the three addresses before you insert the opportunity.  Those addresses link directly to the opportunity.  You have to create the main document in the graph before you can add the lower level entries.  Think of it as trying to write the addresses before you've gotten out an envelope for the letter you're sending.
